# Как изменить размер миниатюры в fancybox?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

Всем добро! То ли я дурак, то ли лыжи не катят. Не могу разобраться как увеличить размер миниатюры в fancybox, установленного на сайте битрикс. Если лезу в код CSS, меняя ширину/высоту,то рушатся пропорции.

Где именно этот параметр можно изменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документацию по fancybox заглядывали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрите еще, может в админке сайта есть переопределение размеров.